# How to remove all color from SVG image in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, png, file-format

I have this PNG image and I need to erase "all" colors, including the white light on front, vest and belly, seeing only the outlines' image, because once that's done, I'm gonna convert it to SVG. [This is the image I need to edit](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xgvrzo02m9fl95/homerbuddha.svg?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove that in Illustrator, because Illustrator is built around editing vector files, and PNG is not vector artwork, it is a raster format (made of pixels).

You can however, attempt to do this in Photoshop — which works with pixels — using the 'Levels' panel.

[image]